# Problems to show icons in may MenuTabBar just load to main view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

I 'm starting to develop ios and I 'm making an app that uses a MenuTabBarController for navigation between screens, the problem I am having is the following :

to start the main screen after going to the login screen , just load the main screen does not display icons TabBar , only shows the letters and icon that is active . this only happens to me in ios 7 and above .

```
UITabBarController *tabVC = (UITabBarController *) self;
NSLog(@"%@", tabVC);
NSArray *unselectedImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"ic_action_cloud_un",  @"ic_action_solicitud_un", @"ic_action_consulting_un", @"ic_action_admin_un",  nil];

NSArray *selectedImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"ic_action_cloud",  @"ic_action_solicitud", @"ic_action_consulting", @"ic_action_admin",  nil];

NSArray *items = self.tabBar.items;
NSLog(@"%@", items);
for (int idx = 0; idx < items.count; idx++){

    UITabBarItem *item = [items objectAtIndex:idx];

    UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[selectedImages objectAtIndex:idx]];
    UIImage *unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[unselectedImages objectAtIndex:idx]];

    [item setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*setFinishedSelectedImage* is deprecated in iOS 7.

You can use these methods instead:

```
[item setImage:[unselectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[item setSelectedImage:[selectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

Comment: still gives me the same problem. :(